# How to get rod of attribute error : 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Tags: python, csv

```
x_train-X_train.ilocI:,:].values
Y train Y train.iloc[:].values
```

Comment: This doesn't look right, please fix the typos in your code.

Answer (score 0):

`iloc` is a `pandas.DataFrame` method, you're trying to call it on a `numpy.ndarray`